# How to click on the checbox from a list of checkboxes available inside a table using selenium

Tags: selenium, xpath, checkbox, webdriver, protractor

I have been trying to click on the one particular checkbox, but all the checkboxes have the same tags and parameters inside. Only the text which is the name of the check box is varying, but unfortunately couldn't get that also to be used. Kindly do help me with this.

Html code:

```
<tr class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="group in groupsList | orderBy:'groupName'">
<td class="col-xs-4 ng-binding">
<input class="ng-scope ng-pristine ng-valid" type="checkbox" checklist-value="group" ng-model="checked"/>
 Checkbox1 name
<br/>
</td>
</tr>
<!-- end ngRepeat: group in groupsList | orderBy:'groupName' -->
<tr class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="group in groupsList | orderBy:'groupName'">
<td class="col-xs-4 ng-binding">
<input class="ng-scope ng-pristine ng-valid" type="checkbox" checklist-value="group" ng-model="checked"/>
 Checkbox2 name
<br/>
</td>
</tr>
<!-- end ngRepeat: group in groupsList | orderBy:'groupName' -->
<tr class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="group in groupsList | orderBy:'groupName'">
<td class="col-xs-4 ng-binding">
<input class="ng-scope ng-pristine ng-valid" type="checkbox" checklist-value="group" ng-model="checked"/>
 Checkbox3 name
<br/>
</td>
</tr>
<!-- end ngRepeat: group in groupsList | orderBy:'groupName' -->
<tr class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="group in groupsList | orderBy:'groupName'">
<td class="col-xs-4 ng-binding">
<input class="ng-scope ng-pristine ng-valid" type="checkbox" checklist-value="group" ng-model="checked"/>
 Checkbox4 name
```

Answers would be very much helpful and appreciated.

The `xpaths` I have tried:

```
//table/tbody/tr/td/input/following-sibling::text()
```

this is highlighting all the texts i.e names of checkboxes

```
//table/tbody/tr/td/input/following-sibling::br/preceding::text()='Checkbox name'

//table/tbody/tr/td/input/text()\[preceding::br and contains(../text(),'Checkbox name')\][1]
```

Answer (score 2):

You should try using following `xPath` to select `checkbox` which is based on `visible text` :-

```
//td[contains(., 'Checkbox1 name')]/input
```

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in the question, your purpose is to click on the checkbox.

You can select the input tag with the exact text:

```
//input[.="Checkbox1 name"]
```

or if you think there could be some extra spaces or text around the text, then you can use contains function:

```
//input[contains(., "Checkbox1 name")]
```

Comment: Tried , but didn't detect the check box as it is in the table I guess we are suppose to give the td or tr tag at the start. input might not work. Thanks for the help :-)

Comment: It should work. Please confirm that the tags are not inside a frame tag.

Comment: @VikasNehaOjha `input` tag is close then the text present `Checkbox1 name`..so the text is not inside `input`...but it's inside `td`...

Comment: Yeah, I realized that

Answer (score 0):

Also you can select by index:

```
element(by.tagName('table')).all(by.tagName('input')).get(INDEX).click();
```

Comment: //td[contains(., 'Checkbox1 name')]/input is working fine. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Check this - protractor allows to search byCssContaining text -

http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.cssContainingText

It might be better than xPath.

Here is for your question:

```
function clickCheckboxByName (name) {
    var checkbox = element(by.cssContainingText("input[type='checkbox']", name));
    checkbox.click();
}
```